# French :: exchange variation - but not quite

Tags: opening, theory, french-defense

I had the following in a game

```
  [FEN ""]
1. e4 e6 2. Nf3 d5
```

expecting White to follow with Nc3 leading to the [Two Knight's Variation of the French](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_Defence#Early_deviations_for_White)

Instead, the game continuing with:

```
  [FEN ""]
1. e4 e6 2. Nf3 d5 3.exd5 exd5 4.d4
```

transposing, I guess to some form of the exchange variation although the typical  "exchange variation" happens in the French's main line: 1. e4 e6 2. d4 d5. Anyhow, is there a name for this opening and how should Black continue? (e.g. with 4....Bb4+ maybe?). Alternatively, might there be any merit in the adventurous 3...Qxd5 which loses a tempo for Black if followed by 4.Nc3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The game has transposed to a standard exchange variation, a variation pretty well explained on [Wikipedia.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_Defence#Exchange_Variation%3a_3.exd5_exd5)
You could try a setup with `4... Bd6`, `5... Ne7`, with the idea that if white puts his best  bishop on `Bd3`, you can play `Bf5` to change it off. Black is very comfortable.

The move `4... Bb4+` is not to be recommended, since it only helps white, giving them the free move `5.c3`.

`3...Qxd5` should be avoided since in the Scandinavian positions that arise, it is important to develop the `c8` bishop before playing `e6`.

Comment: I like the idea of exchanging Black's bad bishop for White's good bishop. However, and not wanting to be pedantic I still maintain that the game has not transposed to the standard exchange variation as White does not have a knight in f3 in the standard exchange.

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus, it has transposed to the French Exchange where White has opted for `4.Nf3` instead of `4.Bd3`. I find 38,649 games in my database that reach the position after `1.e4 e6 2.d4 d5 3.exd5 exd5`. While `4.Bd3` is the most popular next move (played 42.2% of the time), `4.Nf3` is second (played 34.8% of the time), with all other choices well behind. So Dag's referring to this position as "a standard exchange variation" seems accurate.